# Eclipse Fonts Looking Weird

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

Good Evening developers, I'm currently trying to find the cause of the following problem:

[image: Weird Looking Font Face]

```
                                (Using Segoe UI 9)
```

As you can see, my eclipse font looks weird as hell, and it's not because of the actual font family and size I'm using, that happens to almost all Microsoft Fonts (Verdana, Times New Roman, etc..).

Consolas doesn't reproduce this. I'm currently running Java 1.8.0_73 on Eclipse Mars 2 (Release 4.5.2 - Build 2016-02-18-0600) but this issue happens on other Eclipse versions (and Java too).

Comment: Describe what you mean by "weird." One person's "weird" might be someone else's "beautiful."

Comment: @E-Riz code blocks "{}" are small just like the statements and methods, where a enum variable is looking big and comments are small. What I want basically is that they look the same size, just like Consolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using a monospaced font for code. There are lots of articles on the interwebs about programming fonts (many recommend Consolas, for example). Using a monospaced font will go a long way toward making your code more readable onscreen.

Second, go to Eclipse **Preferences** > **General** > **Appearance** > **Colors and Fonts** and use the *Restore Defaults* button to set things back to the default state. That will eliminate any customizations that might be setting certain code elements using larger font sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yet default font won't fix that problem, so I guess I'm sticking with Consolas.